# admin-ajax error 400

Tags: ajax, child-theme

I've gotten the following code to work when I put it in functions.php of a theme, but because it was causing other pages to have errors, I've created a child theme and am attempting to put the code in there.  But now I'm getting a error 400 code.

My child themes style.css file:

```
/*
Theme Name: Agent Search
Theme URI: http: //mysite.com/
Description: This is a custom child theme I have created.
Author: My Name
Author URI: http: //mysite.com/
Template: page-builder-framework
Version: 0.1
*/
@import url("../page-builder-framework/style.css");
```

My functions.php file:

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );
function enqueue_parent_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}

add_action('wp_ajax_zip_search', 'zip_search');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_zip_search', 'zip_search' );
function zip_search()
{
    global $wpdb;
    
    //  Functional code omitted for now.  Just need to get "here" paragraph return (for now)
    
    $output = "<p>here</p>";
    $response = array(
        'data' => $output,
    );

    wp_send_json_success($response);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_load_scripts' );
function my_load_scripts() {

    // Enqueue javascript on the frontend.
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'zip_js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '-child-agent_search/js/zip_search.js',
        array('jquery')
    );

    // The wp_localize_script allows us to output the ajax_url path for our script to use.
    wp_localize_script(
        'zip_js',
        'myAjax',
        array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) )
    );
}

?>
```

And my zip_search.js file is:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    console.log("Document loaded");
    
    jQuery("#searchButton").click( function(e) {
      console.log("Search button clicked");
      e.preventDefault(); 
      var zipCode = document.getElementById("inputField").value;
   
      var data = {
        'action' : "zip_search",
        'zip_code' : zipCode
      };

      console.log("Zip code entered: " + data.zip_code);
      console.log("WP AJax URL: " + data.action);
   
      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",
         url : data.action,
         data : data,
      
         success: function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            if(response.success) {
                console.log("response.type == success");
                jQuery("#results").html(response.data.data);
            }
            else {
                console.log("response.type == else");
                console.log(response.data);
            }
         },
         error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log("In error, error thrown!");
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
      })  
   })
});
```

Again, this worked when the code was placed directly in the parents functions.php. Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thank you all in advance!

## =========
Edit 1:10pm CST 07/22/2020

I just changed the action to "zip_search".

Also wanted to mention I am using "Multiple Themes Plugin" so I can have this one page use the child theme I am creating.

## =========
Edit 8:40am CST 07/23/2020

I asked a new (better) question to solve my problem at: [Targeting single page with JS](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/371642/184205)

Comment: In `data` you’ve set the `action` to the URL. It’s supposed to be `zip_search`.

Comment: Have you considered using the REST API instead to handle your AJAX requests? It's much easier to debug

Comment: @JacobPeattie - Ah, thanks for point that out.  I did have that one point, but in my trying to figure it out, that got switch (recently).  I've changed it back to "zip_search".  But still doesn't work.  Editing it above now.

Comment: @TomJNowell - To be honest, I am not the best at web dev.  Work needed this added to Wordpress and I started to get over my head.  Do you have a link to an example or something I could work with to try it out?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: tbh it would take me longer to fully secure and add an Admin AJAX endpoint than it would a REST API endpoint, look up `register_rest_route`. Keep in mind though, that by using the multiple themes plugin, it's plausible that anything answer you get will not work for you if it's code inside a theme, it's a massive spanner in the works that complicates everything in ways most people won't understand. How does WP know which theme to load for the AJAX endpoint?

Comment: @TomJNowell -  Honestly, I have no clue.  I caved in and used the plugin because the code I put in functions.php and the JS file kept messing up other pages on WP.  I figured I needed to create a child theme and migrate my code, and have the page use that child theme.  Is that the wrong direct to go?

Comment: Making a theme only apply to a specific page is highly unusual. Normally if people want to style a page differently they have 2 popular options. If the markup needs to change, they can use a page template. If it's just the styling/CSS then they can use the body class selectors to apply rules only to that page. It might be a better idea to ask about how to target just a single page with JS in WP, usually by only running code when a page has a certain body class, or only enquing the JS on that page. Never ask how to fix your solution, ask how to fix the original problem, and show what you tried

Comment: Undestood.  I will formulate a new question.  Just for giggles, I'll state me objective here.  I added new tables in the backend and created a custom search to query the DB and return rows that match my (complex) query.  Everything was good until we found other pages were messing up.  

Thanks for the info and I'll link in my new question to this thread as soon as I get it posted.  

Thanks again!

Comment: Hello Everyone!  I've created a new question and wanted to share it here in case anyone else was attempting the same thing, knows where I went with it:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/371642/184205