# Move custom code out of theme's functions.php file

Tags: themes

I have written code to use on a single page, but I've placed it in the theme's functions.php and created a javascript file and placed it in the theme's JS directory.

Recently, the theme was updated and functions.php was overwritten and JS file disappeared.

Where do I need to put this code so when the theme is updated, my code will not be lost?

functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_zip_search', 'zip_search');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_zip_search', 'zip_search' );
function zip_search()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $zip = $_REQUEST["zip_code"];   


/**/

    $query = 'SELECT zone FROM Counties WHERE zip = %s';
    $zone = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare($query, $zip) );

    $output = "<h1>".$zone."</h1>";
    $t_zone = $zone;
    $trimmed_zone = trim($t_zone);

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM Managers WHERE zone = %s;';
    $manager_info = $wpdb->get_row(  $wpdb->prepare($query, $trimmed_zone) );

    $output .= "<table style=\"width:100%\">" . 
                    "<tr>".
                        "<th>Zone Manager</th>".
                        "<th>Phone</th>".
                        "<th>Email Address</th>".
                    "</tr>" .
                    "<tr>" . 
                        "<td>" . $manager_info->first_name . " " . $manager_info->last_name  . "</td>" . 
                        "<td>" . $manager_info->phone_number . "</td>" . 
                        "<td>" . $manager_info->email_address .  "</td>" . 
                    "</tr>" .
                "</table>";

    $query = 'SELECT Region_Number FROM Zones WHERE Zone = %s';
    $region = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare($query, $zone) );

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM Agblist WHERE Region_Number = %s';
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare($query, $region) );
    
    $output .= "<table style=\"width:100%\">";
    
    $output .= "<tr>".
                "<th>Company Name</th>".
                "<th>Contact Info</th>".
                "<th>Channel</th>".
                "<th>Territory</th>".
               "</tr>";

    foreach( $results as $result ) 
    {
        $output .= "<tr>".
                        "<td>".$result->Company_Name."</td>".
                        "<td>".$result->Corp_Address_Line_1."</br>".$result->Corp_Address_Line_2."</br>".$result->Corp_City.", ".$result->Corp_State." ".$result->Corp_Zip_Code."</br>".$result->Office_Phone_1."</td>".
                        "<td>".$result->Channel."</td>".
                        "<td>".$result->Agent_Territory."</td>".
                    "</tr>";
    }
    //$output .= "<li>Result: ".$results."</li>";
    $output .= "</table>";
/**/
    //$output = "<p>here</p>";
    $response = array(
        'data' => $output,
    );

    wp_send_json_success($response);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_load_scripts' );
function my_load_scripts() {

    // Enqueue javascript on the frontend.
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'zip_js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/zip_search.js',
        array('jquery')
    );

    // The wp_localize_script allows us to output the ajax_url path for our script to use.
    wp_localize_script(
        'zip_js',
        'myAjax',
        array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) )
    );

}
```

/js/zip_search.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
   console.log("Document loaded!");
   jQuery("#AgentSearchButton").click( function(e) {
      console.log("Search button clicked");
      e.preventDefault(); 
      var zipCode = document.getElementById("AgentInputField").value;
      console.log("Zip code entered: " + zipCode);
      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",
         url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
         data : {
             'action': "zip_search",
             'zip_code' : zipCode
         },
         success: function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            if(response.success) {
                console.log("response.type == success");
                jQuery("#results").html(response.data.data);
            }
            else {
                console.log("response.type == else");
                console.log(response.data);
            }
         },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log("In error, error thrown!");
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
      })
   })
});
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Comment: To prevent future overrides you need to create a child theme, check the wordpress docs about this, heres a [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)

Comment: Thank you!  I almost came back with, "done that, didn't work", but I have been massaging this code to work out the bugs, and previous posts I've made solved problems that I was having, and this last little bit was what I needed!  Much appreciated!

Comment: You can also create a custom plugin if you want the code to continue working regardless of what theme is used.  Sometimes for a one off function I prefer to build it as a plugin rather than go the child theme route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In previous questions you mentioned that you created a child theme and installed the multiple themes plugin so that you could put code on a specific page on your site. So you've been using child themes in a way that they weren't intended to be used.

Instead, think of a child theme as a transparency, a layer over the top of your theme. You create a child theme, and place custom code in it, then activate that child theme instead of the theme you were using. WP will load both themes, preferring the template files in the child theme.

This way, because all your changes are in the child theme, when the parent theme is updated no loss occurs.

Comment: Hello!  Yes, through this, I've learned to use a child so that it decouples from the parent code.  My code was overwritten a few times.  I believed I needed to have multiple themes because the code was messing up other pages, and if I only targeted a single page with my code, that wouldn't happen.

Because we fixed the issue of having duplicate element IDs, I learned I didn't need to have that single page with it's own theme.  After getting my code to work in the parent theme without messing up other pages, I moved the code back over to the child theme I created and activated it.

Comment: Very thankful for your and everyone's help!  I tried to figure it out on my own, but your suggestion to ask for how to complete my task, opposed to how to solve the current issue I was facing resulted in me asking better questions and getting better answers.

Comment: That's awesome to hear! Glad we could help :)